# Extra column returned in PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, resultset

I'm using PDO to inner join three tables: "Users", "Teams" and the intermediary table "teams_users".  "teams_users" handles the many to many relationship between Users and Teams.  Many Users can be on a team.  Each Team can have many users.

The idea is to get an array back of team IDs from the "teams" table where the user has permission (which is in the table teams_users).

$username is passed into the function.

When $query is echoed it looks like this:

```
SELECT teams_users.team_id FROM users INNER JOIN teams_users ON users.id = teams_users.user_id INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = teams_users.user_id WHERE users.username = :username ORDER BY teams.id ASC

public function findTeamsByUsername($username = "") {
    $query = "SELECT teams_users.team_id " .
            "FROM users " .
            "INNER JOIN teams_users " .
            "ON users.id = teams_users.user_id " .
            "INNER JOIN " . $this->table . " " .
            "ON " . $this->table . ".id = teams_users.user_id " .
            "WHERE users.username = :username " .
            "ORDER BY teams.id ASC";
    echo $query;

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $r = $stmt->execute();
//        $stmt->debugDumpParams();

    if (!$r) {
        return null;
    } else {
        // $teamSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $teamSet = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $teamSet;
    }
}
```

The output in MySQL Workbench is:
team_id
1
2

The output in PHP is:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [team_id] => 1 **[0] => 1** ) [1] => Array ( [team_id] => 2 **[0] => 2** ) )

The output in PHP makes sense except for where is the [0]=>1 and [0]=>2 coming from?  What I don't understand is in bold. Shouldn't the select be returing one column?

Bonus points for simplifying the return to be a single array of ID like this: [1,2]

Comment: Open a manual please http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php.

Comment: Thanks for the manual referral.  My rule of thumb is to spend 20-30 minutes on a problem before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)` instead. [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) by default will return a "mixed" array with both associative and numeric indices.